# MVC - Ajax form - return partial view doesnt update in <div> target

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I have an index view that I want to update automatically as the user types in a client id. I got something similiar to work (only it was updating just a label) - but this will not work.

What happens is the partial is just rendered by itself (not in place of the UpdateTargetID). So the data is rendered on a new page. Here is my code:

Controller:

```
public ActionResult ClientList(string queryText)
    {
        var clients = CR.GetClientLike(queryText);
        return PartialView("ClientIndex", clients);
    }
```

Partial View:

```
<table>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <td>Client ID</td>
        <td>Phone1</td>
        <td>Phone2</td>
        <td>Phone3</td>
        <td>Phone4</td>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <% if (Model != null)
       {
           foreach (Client c in Model)
           { %>
        <tr>
            <td><%= Html.Encode(c.ClientID)%></td>
            <td><%= Html.Encode(c.WorkPhone)%></td>
            <td><%= Html.Encode(c.WorkPhone1)%></td>
            <td><%= Html.Encode(c.WorkPhone2)%></td>
            <td><%= Html.Encode(c.WorkPhone3)%></td>

        </tr>
    <% }
       } %>
</tbody>
```

Main View:

Insert code messed up, so this is just copy/pasted:

$(function() {
            $("#queryText").keyup(function() {
                $('#sForm').submit();
            });
        });

```
  <div id="status" class="status" name="status">
    <%--<% Html.RenderPartial("ClientIndex", ViewData["clients"]); %> Should this be here???? --%>

  </div>
```

Comment: EDIT:  (only it was updating just a label)

Comment: By the way I have visited http://jarrettatwork.blogspot.com/2009/02/aspnet-mvc-ajax-brief-introduction.html - great link with very useful information. Ive also done a lot of googling but still can't get it right.

Comment: Jack, I have the exact same problem. It should update the div but it doesn't. How did you manage to solve that problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than posting a form on the page constantly why not do a behind the scenes jQuery.get call to get the search results for the provided text.  I would think this would be faster and cleaner.  When submitting the form like I think you are (judging from my reading of your code) you are causing the page to essentially refresh (and not re-write to the div).

```
$('#sForm').submit()
```

Comment: How might I go about doing that? I've seen some examples of basic jQuery.get usage, but what is the syntax for passing the form data (from the text box)? Is it just simply $("#queryText").val(); ? I have not messed with json results at all.

Comment: You might find this article helpful! http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=435&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.

In my partial view, I had this

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl" %>
```

but it should have been this

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<IQueryable<Client>>" %>
```

---

an easy way to test if your ajax call is working is to return a string instead of an ActionResult

```
public string ClientList(string queryText)<
{
    return("ok, the ajax call must have worked because I see this string.");
}
```